# PHP adding quotes to both ends of each value of a csv

Tags: php

I am currently attempting to wrap every entry in a csv in quotes for input into an SQL server. currently, I am using this method:

```
$the_row = str_replace(",", "','", $the_row);
$the_row = "'" . $the_row . "'";
```

This works great, except it leaves off the final quote at the end of each row. What is the best way to go about fixing this?

Comment: Any reason you're not using `fputcsv` instead of trying to manually fix the CSV?

Comment: What does *except it leaves off the final quote at the end of each row.* mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: Your second assignment should put quotes at the beginning and end. I don't see how it could be leaving off the final quote.

Comment: It works here: https://ideone.com/spHtDZ

Comment: @MatsLindh It sounds like they're using this to dynamically construct an SQL insert statement. :(